# MongoDB index construction in the background as the default behavior for all connections

Tags: java, database, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

We need to override the default value for `background` option in `createIndex` method of **MongoDB**, to `true`, so that if a developer forgets to pass the option, it runs in the background.

Is there any way to override this option at the driver, connection or any other levels?

Specifically for, but not only limited to, *Java*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Spring Data MongoDB you'd have to override the `ensureIndex` method of `IndexOperations` via `DefaultIndexOperations` and return that one for `MongoOperations#indexOps(...)`.
By doing so you'll be able to capture all index creation, also the annotation driven one.

```java
@Configuration
public class Config extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    @Override
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {

        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory(), mappingMongoConverter()) {

            @Override
            public IndexOperations indexOps(Class<?> entityClass) {

                return new DefaultIndexOperations(this, getCollectionName(entityClass), entityClass) {

                    @Override
                    public String ensureIndex(IndexDefinition indexDefinition) {

                        if(indexDefinition instanceof Index) {
                            ((Index)indexDefinition).background();
                        }

                        return super.ensureIndex(indexDefinition);
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }

    // ...
}
```

For annotations you may also use your own custom annotation pinning the `background` attribute to a fixed value without the option to override it, while opening up modifiable values via `@AliasFor`.
Something like in the sample below works without having to customize `MongoOperations` / `IndexOperations`.

```java
@Indexed(background = true) // fix attribute values here
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
public @interface ComposedIndexedAnnotation {

    @AliasFor(annotation = Indexed.class, attribute = "unique")
    boolean unique() default false;

    @AliasFor(annotation = Indexed.class, attribute = "name")
    String indexName() default "";
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, can you give some hints or examples for the first part of your answer?

Comment: @ehsun7b I updated the answer to explain the first approach in more detail.

Answer (score -1):

Here is one solution for Spring data mongodb or mongodb-java-driver:

```
public static void insertIndex(MongoCollection<Document> collection) {
  //Create the json document describing your index
  Document textIndexes = new Document("dataset.metadata.description.text", "text");

  //set your index options
  IndexOptions io = new IndexOptions();
  io.name("my_index");
  io.background(true);

  //create your index for your collection
  collection.createIndex(textIndexes, io);
}
```

Spring data mongodb `@Indexed` annotation also comes with various properties that allow you to control how the index is applied. [See reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/index/Indexed.html)

```
@Indexed(background= true)
```

Comment: What if the indexes are created via the `@Indexed` annotation, does this still impact those index constructions?

Comment: No. you'll need to set up your option within the annotation. see my edit.

Comment: Of course I know about `@Indexed(background= true)`, my question is, how to override the default value if the developer doesn't pass any value for `background`. It seems you even didn't read my question completely. 